# Slideshow image with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am managing a website for my company that was made by someone else ($24,000) and we edited the slideshow which has images with buttons on the bottom that navigate to the corresponding photo. What we did was add an image with a link and a button to the slideshow. The problem is it works fine in chrome but not in I.E.. In I.E. the button is there but the last button just gives a blank image (the image we added went in the first button). It also gives a strange border around the first (added) image. Here is the HTML. the new first image has a link where the others do not. I have looked through the javascript and jquery and it doesn't appear to dictate anything about how many images/buttons are allowed or anything. Sorry for the long code and I appreciate you taking the time to read it.

`<a href="http:\\www.supplysourceoutlet.com" target="_blank">
<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-outlet.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325"></a>`

`<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-01.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">`
 `<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-02.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">`
 `<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-03.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">`
 `<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-04.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">`
 `<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-05.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">`

```
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paging">
            <a href="#" rel="1">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" rel="2">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" rel="3">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" rel="4">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" rel="5">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" rel="6">&nbsp;</a>'
```

Here is the javascript for the slideshow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Show the paging and activate its first link
$(".paging").show();
$(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

//Get size of the image, how many images there are, then determine the size of the image reel.
var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

//Adjust the image reel to its new size
$(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

//Paging  and Slider Function
rotate = function(){
    var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

    $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
    $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

    //Slider Animation
    $(".image_reel").animate({
        left: -image_reelPosition
    }, 500 );

}; 

//Rotation  and Timing Event
rotateSwitch = function(){
    play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 7 seconds
        $active = $('.paging a.active').next(); //Move to the next paging
        if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
            $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
        }
        rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
    }, 7000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (7 seconds)
};

rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

//On Hover
$(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
}, function() {
    rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation timer
}); 

//On Click
$(".paging a").click(function() {
    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
    //Reset Timer
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation timer
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the border and that only the first (added) one links is because it is the only one with an a tag around it. You could add a border="0" to the img tag to get rid of the border like this:

```
<a href="http:\\www.supplysourceoutlet.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-outlet.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="684" height="325">
</a>
```

To fix the other part I need to know where the div with the class image_reel is located could you post more of your html?

Comment: thanks for the response. The border is gone. the image_reel class is the class the html I posted is in so right before the <a href="http:\\www.supplysource...." is "<div id="slideshow">
                <div class="window">
      <div class="image_reel">

Comment: Can you see if the image is being included? It may have something to do with the math `code`var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide`code`

Comment: All I did was make it "image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth +1;" And it works now. The Wilhelm, you da best!